# Change default location of sdkconfig file

Tags: cmake, build, esp32, esp-idf, kconfig

The project is based on ESP-IDF v4.
It can be built for several platforms.

Currently I'm trying to enable full out-of-source build approach and `sdkconfig` is the only auto-generated file that remains in the source tree. By default it is saved in the root directory of a cmake project.

Is there any way to change the default location of `sdkconfig` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SDKCONFIG` variable to set the path you need.

Set it in your `CMakeLists.txt` file like this :

`set(SDKCONFIG "C:/path/to/your/folder/sdkconfig")`